# Access Yuutube Url MPMoviePlayerController without video file name

Tags: iphone

i m access Youtube url -: http://www.youtube.com/v/9Na-LXU5m3g?f=videos&app=youtube_gdata
but MpMoviePlayerController dont show the video .

```
movieURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/9Na-LXU5m3g?f=videos&amp;app=youtube_gdata"]; 
mpMoviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  initWithContentURL:movieURL]; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver: self
     selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
     name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object: mpMoviePlayerController];

    [mpMoviePlayerController play];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For you tube videos,display the url in webview.It will automatically play the video in the movie player on tapping the video in the webview.

All the best.

Comment: but in this case done button not quit the player on ipad. there fore i have used MpMOviePlayerController . any other Ideas.